# Jasmine test case failures after upgrade from angular-mock 1.4 to 1.6. Can some one suggest alternate to below implementation?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine, window.location, angular-mock

Below is the loginService class :

```
 export default function loginService($http, loginCallbackService) {
    const service = {};
    service.Login = login;
    return service;

    function login(username, password) {
        $http.post('/OpUi/coreOpUi/controller/v1/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            loginCallbackService.handleLoginSuccess(response, username);
        }, function (response) {

        });
    };
}
loginService.$inject = ['$http', 'loginCallbackService'];
```

Where loginCallbackService manages all the callback methods , this is how it looks :

```
    export default function loginCallbackService($window) {
    const service = {};
    service.handleLoginSuccess = handleLoginSuccess;
    return service;

    function handleLoginSuccess(response, username) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            $window.location = 'mainApp.html';
        }
    }
}
    loginCallbackService.$inject = ['$window'];
```

The loginCallbackService.spec.js file looks like below :

```
const  LoginCallbackService = require('../../../js/core/services/LoginCallbackService.js');

describe("To test LoginCallbackService class", function() {
    let $window;

angular.module('testLoginCallbackService', [])
.service('$window', () => ({
        location: 'mainApp.html'
}))
.service('LoginCallbackService', LoginCallbackService);

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('testLoginCallbackService'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$window_) {
    $window = _$window_;
}));

it('should be able to navigate to mainApp.html with correct response', () => {
    const response = {
            status: 200,
            headers: function(value) {
                return "token"
            }
    };
    const testUsername = "user1";
    mockLoginCallbacksService.handleLoginSuccess(response, testUsername);
    expect($window.location).toBe('mainApp.html');
});
});
```

Note : Below are the errors i get :

```
    [INFO]  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$window.angular.callbacks') (line 13103)
[INFO]  node_modules/angular/angular.js:13103:36
[INFO]  invoke@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4862:24
[INFO]  node_modules/angular/angular.js:4656:43
[INFO]  getService@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4803:39
[INFO]  injectionArgs@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4828:68
[INFO]  invoke@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4854:31
[INFO]  $get@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4729:49
[INFO]  invoke@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4862:24
[INFO]  node_modules/angular/angular.js:4656:43
[INFO]  getService@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4803:39
[INFO]  injectionArgs@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4828:68
[INFO]  invoke@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4854:31
[INFO]  WorkFn@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3170:26
[INFO]  loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
[INFO]  inject@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3137:28
[INFO]  C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js:88:23
[INFO]  C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js:50:10
[INFO]  __webpack_require__@C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js:20:34
[INFO]  C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js:40:37
[INFO]  global code@C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js:41:12
[INFO]  TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. in C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js (line 102)
[INFO]  C:/Users/askumar/Perforce/askumar_MOB700099_675/LYSIS/OpUi/MAIN/ml-sp-opui-core/ml-sp-opui-core-client/src/main/webapp/test/unit/services/LoginCallbackService.spec.js:102:28
[INFO]  loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
```

Note : loading of packages is via npm.

i triaged and realized the error is with the line $window.location = 'mainApp.html'; in loginCallbackService.js . 
But the same test case were successful with
angular: '~1.4.8'
angular-mocks: '~1.4.8' but not with '~1.6.1'.

Can someone help me here please ?